# How to trigger button by pressing enter in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, keydown, enter, onkeydown

Is it possible to trigger my "Add" button by pressing enter on the keyboard?

////

[image]

This is the last div in the form, for the third gap:

```
  <div fd-form-item *ngIf="targetType.value != null">
    <label fd-form-label for="input-showroom-hostname" [required]="true">URL:</label>
    <fd-form-input-message-group>
      <input
        fd-form-control
        type="text"
        id="input-showroom-hostname"
        placeholder="e.g. l2w.demo.hybris.com"
        formControlName="hostname"
        [state]="determineFormControlState(hostname)"
      />
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasRequiredErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ REQUIRED }} </fd-form-message>
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasShowroomUserRightsErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ SHOWROOM_USER_RIGHTS }}</fd-form-message>
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasPatternErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ URL_PATTERN }} </fd-form-message>
    </fd-form-input-message-group>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's : (keydown.enter)="addShowroom()"

Comment: nothing is required to make it work. `button` elements already trigger `click` handler when you press enter while this button is in focus. No changes needed

Comment: Can you provide more code from the component.html and component.ts, so we can deduct the context?

Comment: I've added full html

Comment: It's working fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t49oov 

Is the button disabled, does it have focus?

Comment: Button is activated once the form below is filled out

Comment: Sounds like it is unlikely that your button has the focus.

A form below? I don't see a form below in your code. 

Do you want to call `addShowRoom()` without the add button having focus, please elaborate when exactly you want to call the function.

Comment: I added the screen of the component. Once all three brackets are filled, the add button is activated and should be also triggered by pressing enter button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function (button) after pressing enter in Angular forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149636/calling-a-function-button-after-pressing-enter-in-angular-forms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add an event on the last input element and the button. Use `(keydown.enter)='add_showroom()'` on the last input.

Below is some minimal code of the idea. Also check the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmrmmv) if you want.

**xx.component.html**

```
<button (click)='add_showroom()'>Add</button><br>
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select><br>
<input (keydown.enter)='add_showroom()' type='text'/>
```

**xx.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public add_showroom() {
    alert('adding showroom');
  }
}
```

Some extra tips:

- Check if the form is valid before processing the enter click.
- Add `(keydown.enter)='add_showroom()'` only to the last element. This is generally speaking better than adding it to an area or multiple elements, because that could lead to unexpected behaviour for someone using `enter` to navigate somewhere. Or using enter to select a value from a dropdown.
- Be very careful using this. Your user may not expect an enter click to submit the form. So UX-wise it is a bit of a grey area. At least notify your user about this behaviour somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should add HostListener Attribute for detecting key press events:

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        this.addShowroom();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add one thing here. `keyCode` is deprecated. You can use `event.key === "Enter"`