# Calling a function (button) after pressing enter in Angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I want to call a function by pressing the enter key to submit the filled out form. I've found below resolution with enums, but not sure how make it work

To use this module, import the Key enum at the top of your TypeScript file using the enum:

```
import { Key } from 'ts-keycode-enum';
```

You can now use a readable enum value in place of any raw keycodes throughout the file:

```
if (ev.which === Key.Escape) { ... }
```

See Key.enum.ts for a complete list of available keys.

In addition, to aid with readability, a number of enum values have aliases. For example:

```
// this  true - these values are equal
Key.One === Key.ExclamationMark
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-keycode-enum

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: The package you found is made to simplify readability thanks to enums. Besides, you have to note that it is recommended to use the `ts-key-enum` package instead of `ts-keycode-enum` since `event.which` and `event.keyCode` are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if the button in your form which type is submit could do the things you wanted:

```
<form>
    ...
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!lgForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ReactiveForm or an Angular ngForm, using`(ngSubmit)="saveForm()"` on the form tag should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **keyup.enter** or **keydown.enter**

```
 <button type="submit" (keyup.enter)="submitForm(...)">Submit</button>
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" (keydown.enter)="submitForm(...)">Submit</button>
```